# Grep from end of file

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Is there a way to start the `grep` search from the end of the file instead of the beginning? Here is from the beginning --

```
$ grep -irn 'Qyt13_pUFjQ' ./
```

The information that I am looking for is close to the end of the file, but takes a few minutes to get all the way there from the start.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tac_%28Unix%29

Comment: `tac file | grep 'pattern'` should do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `tac` to read the file line by line from the end to the beginning, then possibly switch it around again with another `tac` if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

You can do `tail -n xxxx file.txt | grep ...` to pipe the last xxxx lines of the file through grep.